# Esoteric error in production: `Type Error: e is undefined`

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm releasing my Vue app into production, but one specific component throws an esoteric error message that I can't trace because all project files are bundled and variable names are changed. This error also is only reproducible in production mode (build), leading me to believe that it's an issue related to the bundling itself.

**Steps to reproduce**

As I mentioned before, the issue is only present in production mode. Therefore I have done my best to reproduce the issue by simply releasing the app on Netlify for reproduction. Here are the steps:

- Visit the app on netlify here: https://grandquest.netlify.com
- Scroll down to the "Sign up" form and create a fake account to test the bug
- Login using these credentials at the login page
- Open the console
- Visit the [world](https://grandquest.netlify.com/world/travel) and click the button that says "Explore Monokai"

Doing this should take you to the faulty route/component (grandquest.netlify.com/map)

**The details**

- The app works perfectly fine in development mode , however (as I will link to), when run in production mode, the app produces an error: Type Error: e is undefined (Mozilla Firefox only, AFAIK) when I mount a specific route.
- Secondly, in the `vue-cli` build logs, I can see various warnings relating to file size limits. Here are the warnings from the build logs:

```
    warning  

    asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
    This can impact web performance.
    Assets: 
    img/gold-frame.536f6ce1.png (415 KiB)
    media/combat-fail.f73de150.mp3 (317 KiB)
    img/monokai-village.84e00e29.png (1.25 MiB)
    img/combat.835c3bee.png (1.04 MiB)
    img/combat-shop.138daeea.png (1.56 MiB)
    img/potions-shop.dea509b2.png (2.07 MiB)
    media/fields-music1.bd10f1d6.mp3 (2.46 MiB)
    img/village-gate.f8c4cfd2.png (3.52 MiB)
    js/chunk-vendors.6c22f97f.js (1.71 MiB)

    warning  

    entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
    Entrypoints:
    app (1.95 MiB)
    js/chunk-vendors.6c22f97f.js
    css/app.fa9c625b.css
    js/app.9440af5a.js


    warning  

    webpack performance recommendations: 
    You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
    For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

    DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
    INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

    ✨ Done in 122.97s.
```

*These two details have led me to believe that the issue is caused by a bundling error*

-

I have tried looking for any variables name `e` inside my code, thinking maybe it was an event, but there are no such variables in my code. It just appears to be a variable that is 'bundled' by vue.

Due to the nature of this error (I am not certain what the variable `e` is in the code because it's obfuscated), I have done my best to summarize the relevant code for the Map component. I would also not mind sharing the entirety of the files if it could help, however, there is no `e` variable to be found.

@/views/Map.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- LOADING SCREEN -->
    <div v-if="!gameInterface.gameInitialized" id="loading-screen">
      <img src="@/assets/img.png" v-on:click="$router.push(`/world`)">
      <div class="tip">Fun fact</div>
      <div class="loading-text">Loading assets</div>
    </div>
    <!-- MAP CONTAINER -->
    <div class="map">
      <button class="exit-button" v-on:click="() => $router.replace({ name: 'world' })">
    EXIT
      </button>
      <!-- CANVAS PARENT -->
      <div
        id="canvas-parent"
        v-on:mousemove="gameInterface.mouseMonitor"
        v-on:mouseleave="gameInterface.pointer.hovering = false"
        v-on:resize="resizeMonitor"
      />
      <!-- RENDER THE SHOP -->
      <Shop v-if="gameInterface.chosenShop"/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { State, Mutation } from 'vuex-class'
// typescript types
import { User } from '@/types';
// vue components
import Shop from '@/components/Shop.vue';
// the game controller
import gameInterface from '@/game/places/map.ts';

@Component({
  components: { Shop }
})
export default class Map extends Vue {
  @State public user!: User;

  public gameInterface = gameInterface();

  public mounted() {
    if (!this.user.authenticated) {
      return this.$router.replace({ name: 'world' });
    }
    this.gameInterface.launch();
    document.addEventListener('wheel', this.gameInterface.scrollMonitor, true);
  }
  public destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener('wheel', this.gameInterface.scrollMonitor, true);
    this.gameInterface.destroyGame();
  }
}
```

@/game/places/map.ts

```
export default () => {
let game: any = null;

let global = {
  tooltip: {},
  chosenShop: null,
  gameInitialized: false,
  pointer: { x: 0, y: 0, hovering: false },
  launch() {
    if (!game) {
      // here a phaser game is started
      game = new Phaser.Game({
        // ...config here
        created() {
          global.gameInitialized = true;
        },
      });
    }
  },
  destroyGame() {
    if (game) {
      game.destroy();
    }
  },
  mouseMonitor(event) {
    if (!global.gameInitialized) {
      return;
    }

    global.pointer = {
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY,
      hovering: true,
    };
  },
  scrollMonitor(event) {
    if (!game) {
      return;
    }
    if (event.deltaY < 0 && game.scene.scenes[0].cameras.main.zoom < 2) {
      game.camera.zoom += 0.1;
    }
    if (event.deltaY > 0 && game.scene.scenes[0].cameras.main.zoom > 1.15) {
      game.camera.zoom -= 0.1;
    }
  },
  exitShop() {
    if (!game) {
      return;
    }
    global.chosenShop = null;
    game.resume();
  }
};

return global;
};
```

**Expected output**

You should see a loading screen for some time while the assets load, and then a map should appear on the screen. You should be able to, with your cursor, navigate this map up and down, as well as click on the various shops.

**Actual output**

The screen appears to be loading indefinitely because an error has ocurred that has stopped the app. The error should now appear in the console, reading Type error: e is undefined(on Firefox)

Any, and all, help is appreciated with this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this function exist?

```
v-on:resize="resizeMonitor"
```

I'm not seeing it anywhere. I think you'll get this type of error if the function doesn't exist